# How to meet required dependencies in order to install expect pecl extension on Mac OS X?

Tags: osx, software-installation, php, expect

I am attempting to install the expect pecl extension.

> OS version = 10.7.3
>   PHP version 5.3.10 installed via macports
>   expect version 5.45 installed via macports

The command I am executing:

```
sudo pecl -d preferred_state=beta install expect
```

fails with `ld: library not found for -lexpect`

The `libexpect5.45.dylib` file is located in `/opt/local/lib`.
Full output of the install command is [here](http://pastebin.com/KWHk7X0b).

From what I can tell pecl just can not find the libexpect library, I even tried prepending:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/local/lib/expect5.45
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/System/Library/Tcl/8.5/expect5.45
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/local/lib
```

Each location has an `expect5.45.dylib` file.  It did not help. Can anyone help me figure out how to get this extension installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so thanks to some trouble shooting and insights from @geekosaur the answer is "pecl is not generating a correct libtool script to install this extension on MacOSX" at least on my setup anyway.  I really appreciate the discussion and trouble shooting.  Of course my next question is going to be: "How do I fix the pecl install script?" But that's for another board... :)

Comment: To anyone that ever cares I did not fix the pecl script on OS X but I did manage to get the extension [installed](https://plus.google.com/108734317101346711822/posts/SfkYhVUBQgr)

Answer (score 1):

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is not used on OS X, and the equivalent environment variable does not affect `ld` (and can break other things, as unlike on Linux it is the entire library path which means critical libraries like `libSystem.dylib` would no longer be found; on the other hand, `sudo` cleans its environment, so it wouldn't work anyway).  Additionally, that library name would not match `-lexpect`.

For what it's worth, `port contents expect` on my Lion system shows me a `/opt/local/lib/libexpect.a` static library (and `libexpect5.45.a`) but no dylib.  Are you sure it is installed correctly?  Check the output of `port contents expect`.

Comment: port contents expect show that I have /opt/local/lib/expect5.45/libexpect5.45.a and /opt/local/lib/libexpect.a I also found [a bug](https://trac.macports.org/ticket/31478) and repaired the symlink, but pecl install expect still fails.  Should I edit the pecl Makefile ? as you said is the library name different ?

Comment: The question then becomes why `pecl` is looking for a dylib instead of a static lib.  A symlink won't fix that, and I don't know enough about `pecl` to know why it won't use the static library.

Comment: Here is the [output of configure](http://pastebin.com/U63rkuWz) The interesting lines that I see are: "checking for expect support... yes, shared" and "checking specify path to Tcl needed by expect... yes, shared"  The Makefile generated is [here](http://pastebin.com/DYfbiHtF) I am curious about the line: "EXPECT_SHARED_LIBADD = -lexpect -ltcl8.5" as that is where it seems to me to be failing.  Any thoughts on what perhaps I could change that -lexpect part to ? I tried -lexpect5.45 and its still failed but with not found for expect5.45

Comment: The "yes, shared" is incorrect, as it's a static library; although if the script is old enough, it may incorrectly assume that a static library behaves as a shared library (this was normal on PowerPC architectures, including PPC Macs).  The `configure` output in this case is not as helpful as the contents of `config.log`.

Comment: [Here](http://pastebin.com/87UykZqM) is the config log.  I am out of my domain, but in reading it I see that it found shared libraries as you said, and I also notice that its says libtool supports shares libraries. I also am examining the Makefile and I see that at the end the lib tool command expands out to [this](http://pastebin.com/Uk7kQNYz) and do the -I represent include paths ? If so I do not see /opt/local/lib present

Comment: Ok, that's interesting, it passes the right `-I` options but is missing `-L/opt/local/lib`.  Editing the `Makefile` to fix that might well fix it; I don't know why it's missing, though, `pecl` should know to look for libraries there as it knows to look for includes.

Comment: So I kept reading and took a look inside the libtool script that was generated by configure.  I edited that script and changed # Whether or not to build shared libraries.
build_libtool_libs=no

# Whether or not to build static libraries.
build_old_libs=yes based on your input that I had a static library. that allowed make to [finish](http://pastebin.com/iVFeWd1H) Now I believe though since this is done manually I have to fingure out how to complete the pecl portion.  I should also find out how to submit a bug report to the pecl maintainer for this package.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3008/discussion-between-ketema-and-geekosaur)